# My hard-coded string is modified during Upload or Install process!

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, upload, package-install

In my VisualForce page I've used one component three times. This component has an attribute called `tableTitle` which gets a string and shows it on my table. This table component is in a package (let's call it **packageA**) and my VisualForce page is in another managed package (let's call it **packageB**). This is how I used this table component in my visual force page:

```
<packageA:tableComponent ... tableTitle="table1">
<packageA:tableComponent ... tableTitle="table2">
<packageA:tableComponent ... tableTitle="table3">
```

I tested this visualForce page in my org (for packageB) and is working as it should. Then I uploaded packageB and installed it in a test org and opened the page and I noticed that the titles are showing up as:

```
packageB.table1
packageB.table2
table3
```

of course the expected table titles are (table1, table2 and table3). Then I looked at the source code of that page in my test org and here's what I found:

```
<packageA:tableComponent ... tableTitle="packageB.table1">
<packageA:tableComponent ... tableTitle="packageB.table2">
<packageA:tableComponent ... tableTitle="table3">
```

So somehow during upload or install process my hard-coded string is modified and this happened for 2 out of 3 instances of this component which makes me feel like this is random!!

Does anyone know what can be the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: My guess would be that the title you're using is also used somewhere else as an ID or Name and the string parser used in install picked it up. Try changing the title to something more unique. This is a guess so not posted as a full answer.

Comment: I actually did check for that, no where in VisualForce page and controller as well as the component and its controller I'm using this title as a variable name or something. Any other ideas? @gNerb

Comment: Nope sorry, that's just the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: So the first two components have picked up the namespace of the package they were used in?

Comment: @DanielBallinger yes, I also installed it in another org and same thing happened.

Comment: @ashkanent Do you access to Salesforce support? It sounds like a platform bug with the internal code that prefixes namespaces.

Comment: just reported this to SF support, will update here if we get anything back @DanielBallinger

Comment: Update on this: as suggested here, reported this to Salesforce support but since I had standard support not premium support they refused to look into this case and recommended asking this online (in their forums!)